# loading a page according to given url

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url, response, web.xml

My requirements is ,when i type an url it should load its correponding page.

I've 3 doubts:

1. For eg: suppose http://www.flipkart.com was the home page and if i type like

http://www.flipkart.com/dell, then it should check the database whether this url is there or not, if its there then it should load that page otherwise default home page.

2. Also is there any ways to call the controller(im using spring controller) according to url?
3. Is there any ways to give a view(jsp page) as response for specific url using web.xml or any xml?

It will be more helpful if i get these answers. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using Spring-MVC then you have controller's feature that is
>   'RequestMapping' with the help of it you can response for what request
>   what to deliver.

1. if page is not there(like, 404 not found) then,
   i would like to recommend you that configure this in your `web.xml`

like,

```
  <error-page>

       <error-code>404</error-code>

       <location>/Error404.html or homepage.html(as per your req.)</location>
    </error-page>
```

2. If you have been successfully configure `spring-mvc` configuration then `spring-mvc-configure xml` will handle how to get in into `Controller`.
3. same `spring-mvc` feature `InternalResourceViewResolver`  with help of it, you can deliver perticular `jsp` on behalf of perticular `URL`.